# How to SET LIMIT in Joomla Database using php? Users should show according to the Group 2 and 6

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

How to SET LIMIT in Joomla Database with PHP? If logged in users who belongs to group 2 I should see only 3 values and if logged in user who belongs to group 6 I should see only 9 values out of n number of data.

```
<?php 
    $dbo = JFactory::getDBO(); 
    $user=& JFactory::getuser(); 

    $groups = $user->get('groups');

    foreach($groups as $id) {

     echo "<p>Group ID is:" . $id . "</p>";

      // how to assign the limit ?

    if($id ==2){    
        echo  "<ul id='jchat_conference_userslist'></ul>"; //  3 users
    } elseif($id ==6){  
        echo "<ul id='jchat_conference_userslist'></ul>";   // 9 users  
    }

    }?>
```

This is the query

```
<?php 

$query = $this->_db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('*')
            ->from($this->_db->quoteName('#__users'))
            ->where($this->_db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . (int) $userId);
                $query->setLimit(1); // limit is not working
        $this->_db->setQuery($query);
        $data = (array) $this->_db->loadAssoc();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have edited question with query, 
Below code should solve your problem :

```
$query = $this->_db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from($this->_db->quoteName('#__users'));
//$query->where($this->_db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . (int) $userId);
// Note : Above where condition is commented purposely as there will be always only one user with given userid 
$groups = $user->get('groups');
//Note : When user will have the 2 & 3 groups then it will always add the setLimit 2.
if(in_array("2",$groups))
{
    $query->setLimit('2');
}
else if(in_array("3",$groups))
{
    $query->setLimit('3'); // Set limit of 3 on query
}
$this->_db->setQuery($query);
$data = (array) $this->_db->loadAssoc();
```

Still Having some questions,

1. Why you have added where condition if you want multiple records as according to user Group. Because in Joomla's user table id will be PK hence it will not have the multiple users with same user id and hence here no use of setLimit
2. What you want to achieve ?

Comment: Actually different groups are there in Joomla. but I have registered my data one with a group of REGISTER(id:2) and another with MANAGER(id:6). Suppose if 100 users are logged in. So, in this  who belongs to group 2 should see only 3 records  and  group 6  should see only 9 records out of n number of data. This is the condition.

Comment: Then you don't need to have where condition of , id=$userId . If you copy paste the above code given in answer it should solve your problem   ideally. Let me know if you face any issue while implementing this answer :)